# Not able to find account on jungle test net 2.0

Tags: eosio-code, testnet, account-creation

Jungle test has been update to **jungle 2.0**, I have some accounts on previous version . My question is Do I have to create all accounts again because **API endpoints** are changed a bit? Anybody have any Idea ? Also did they put limit over **EOS version** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes jungle testnet upgraded to 2.0 and before updating they have started account migration programme but it's ended now, and they have given manual migration form on this site https://jungletestnet.io/ to migrate your accounts.

Comment: OOOh I have missed the account migration date........